# what is the easiest way to test if a value exists in an object using lodash or angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, find, boolean, lodash

This works if obj is a collection but if I am just trying to test if a value exists in a single object it is not working.  What is the most efficient way using lodash or angularjs to test if a serach term exists within an object?  Thanks!!

```js
var obj = {
  id: 4,
  name: 'test',
  value: 'car',
  description: 'I like soup'
}

var searchTerm=  'soup';

var testObject = function(){  
  var status = true;
  status = _.some(obj, searchTerm);  
  console.dir(status);  
}

testObject();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: !!String(_.values(obj)).match(searchTerm); or without _, !!JSON.stringify(obj).match(searchTerm);

Comment: `it is not working` is really not helping. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @JSilva Your last update to the question, changes it drastically, which is not allowed. So I reverted the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lodash's `_.values` and `_.some` with a predicate to make this work.

```js
var obj = {
  id: 45,
  name: 'test',
  value: 'car',
  description: 'I like soup'
}

var testObject = function(searchTerm){  
  console.log(_.some(_.values(obj), function (s) {
    return _.isString(s) ? s.indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1 : '' + s === searchTerm;
  }));
}

testObject('soup');
testObject('4');
testObject('45');
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works except what if the object contains null values? I updated the object in my question to reflect a more accurate object.

Comment: @JSilva It works fine even with null values. The `_.isString` check ensures that.

Comment: The search term should be against all items in the object, so if I change the search term to 4, this doesn't search against ID.  Is there a way to have it search against non-string items as well?  Thanks so much!

Comment: @JSilva I can't help but find that... odd. Why should it check if a string is *anywhere* within the value, but should match all other types of values exactly?

Comment: We have a input box that allows users to type in a search phrase.  The search phrase will check all columns in a contact record.  This contact record includes their worker ID (number), Phone numbers, dates... all kinds of different fields.  Some are null some are not.  So I am looking for something that checks if the entered value exists within anywhere in the record.

Comment: @JSilva Updated to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple but not optimal way, looks everywhere in the object hierarchy.

```
function hasKeyValue(object, keyValue)
{
return JSON.stringify(object).indexOf(':"'+keyValue+'"') !== -1;
}
```